# Why won't this failable initializer on NSURL (taking optional String) compile?

Tags: swift, initialization, optional-parameters

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why this won't compile. The compiler throws the error the error: `All stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before returning nil from an initializer`.

The error message itself doesn't quite make sense, as a failed initialization is just that, failed. The stored properties should only need to be initialized if the object is actually initialized, no?

When I omit the `else { return nil }`, the compiler throws a different error: `Use of 'self' in delegating initializer before 'self.init' is called`.

```
extension NSURL {
    convenience init?(optionalString: String?) {
        if let string = optionalString {
            self.init(string: string)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The init that you are calling `self.init(string: string)` is itself a convenience initialiser - you should call the full designated initialiser `init?(string URLString: String, relativeToURL baseURL: NSURL?)`.

Comment: Is it not the responsibility of a convenience initializer to ensure all stored properties are being initialized (by either calling the designated initializer or initializing them itself)? I.e., it makes no difference whether I call a designated initializer vs. a convenience initializer in the above failable initializer. (Tried and compiler throws the same error)